# Any side effect if bootstrap.min.css is linked twice

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs with partials html as header. In the main html head,code is run;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>
```

In the partial header.html, `bootstrap.min.css` is linked again.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

The webpage runs normally. Will there be any side effect if `bootstrap.min.css` is linked twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two files are exactly same, Then it does not matter how many times they are included. If they are not the same, the classes form last added file will take precedence in case of conflict.

Comment: Will it slow down page loading slightly?